# Has anyone used iScroll with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, iscroll

Newbie here...

Building an app in Angularjs and now I want to incorporate iScroll features. Has anyone done that before? If so, can you share some tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little late, but I released a AngularJS Directive that helps in getting iScroll to work correctly.  See https://github.com/ibspoof/ng-iScroll

Comment: I tried it and it seems to be working almost fine, except one thing -  when I try to pull a list down, it goes to the top. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried [ng-iScroll](https://github.com/ibspoof/ng-iScroll), but ended up writing [angular-iscroll](https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll) because I wanted the ability to turn iScroll on and off during runtime, and ng-iScroll was unnecessarily complicated (for example, you don't need to specify an element's ID in an Angular directive).

Also, I developed [core-layout](https://github.com/mtr/core-layout), [a demo web app](https://mtr.github.io/core-layout/examples/) showing how the angular-iscroll directive can be used in a responsive-design app with support for both scrolling drawer (slide-out) menus and modals.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the iscroll-scroller div to actually function (there are no css transitions being applied to it).  Is there a way to initialize the scroller inside the controller?  When I log out that the iScrollService.state inside my controller, I get {useIScroll: true}.  Thanks!

Comment: ng-iscroll refers to your repo as being 'less dead': https://github.com/ibspoof/ng-iScroll/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a better question for the angularjs google group. That is where I found this discussion (google search)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/angular/iscroll/angular/EBHrwhPPJyg/VnubgpLKq9IJ